# magento 1.9.0.1 customer cannot login and redirect back to login

Tags: customer, redirect, login

already checked the 1.8 bug with the formkey.

All files have the appropriate addition

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

caches, sessions and cookies cleared.
But still not working.

Any idea how to get that to work?

Cookies seem to work (orders can be placed).

Comment: are you checking on localhost.and which browser ?

Comment: are you using any external javascript? have you tried checking the form action ?

Comment: Can you add more detail? Is the frontend cookie set (along with any others)? Do you have any kind of caching solution in place - Varnish etc?

Comment: it was a combination og htaccess, cookie url and caching ..